# Display input label in content with css

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I have a PHP script that prints disabled input checkboxes.
The script itself is working fine, but im having problems showing data-label in front of checkbox as in normal script, when i render it through drupal..

I fixed most of the issues, but it does not display the data-label/name of the input in front of it - so i was wondering, if there is a way to "call" the data-label/name via CSS content, and place it before the input using :before property.

I have seen one use css content to render title and date using this css content: `attr(data-day-of-month)' 'attr(headers)` so im wondering if there is a way to do the same displaying input labels or data-labels from inputs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `:after` and `:before` pseudo elements (which allow you to style `content`) are not supported for use on replaced elements such as form input fields or images.

As such what you are trying to do will not work unfortunately, you will need to resort to a non CSS solution, such as outputting to a `label` element directly..

[**Replaced Elements from MDN**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Replaced_element)

> In CSS, a replaced element is an element whose representation is
>   outside the scope of CSS. These are kind of external objects whose
>   representation is independant of the CSS. Typical replaced elements
>   are , ,  or forms element like ,
>   . Some elements, like  or  are replaced elements
>   only in specific cases. Object inserted using the CSS content
>   properties are anonymous replaced elements.

**[CSS 2.1 (still relevant) spec on `:before` and `:after`](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/generate.html#before-after-content)**

> This specification does not fully define the interaction of :before
>   and :after with replaced elements (such as IMG in HTML). This will be defined in more detail in a future specification.*

*<sub>Note that this hasnt been defined to date</sub>

Comment: Hmm.. i had a developer make my calendar responsive on a website, and he actually used css content to display the date month and day next to calendar - therefore i thought maybe it was possible to do the same with input name/id ..